# iOS sending a local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I built an app and I would like to run a daily check, see what actions need to be taken by the user. So my first idea is to support a background mode, but then I didn't really find my option in the capabilities tab.

So I decided to go with `background fetch`, implement this method in AppDelegate `func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` and run with it. But I'm not sure whether this is the right way to do it?

All of my app works offline, so I'd like to check some Realm data and then send an appropriate message. How would I do this? I want it to still work when a user closes the app.

Comment: You can send silent push notification to trigger your app

Comment: But that still doesn't cover the whole scala of tasks I need to do to set it up. I mean, I need to run a background mode, right? I need that specific callback I mention in the OP, right?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered on SO. I would close but you have opened a bounty on it.

Comment: I don't think it is too broad, I'm just missing a sense of documentation or answers that could help me out with the existing perimeters of the iOS ecosystem. I mean, this should be relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you need your app to work on something in the background (i.e fetching location of the user in the background even if the device is locked), I believe the approach for this is a bit complex.

Check my answer to this question: [Will Realm still be able to save the data while user has locked iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872866/will-realm-still-be-able-to-save-the-data-while-user-has-locked-iphone/44873203#44873203)

I mentioned there the sample project I used (as a library) for my production level project.

Capabilities of the project?

1. Local notifications
2. Fetching of user location even in the background
3. Sending of users data to the server even in the background
4. Storing the data to local using Core Data and again even in the background.

Additional note, not sure if you know this already (cause almost all iPhone users know this), local notifications won't be seen if the app is opened and is being used.

EDIT (for sample):

**Function for scheduling local notifications supporting iOS 9**

```
private func setUpLocalNotification(hour: Int, minute: Int) {

    // have to use NSCalendar for the components
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: .gregorian)!;

    var dateFire = Date()

    var fireComponents = calendar.components(
        [NSCalendar.Unit.day,
         NSCalendar.Unit.month,
         NSCalendar.Unit.year,
         NSCalendar.Unit.hour,
         NSCalendar.Unit.minute],
        from:dateFire)

    // if today's date is passed, use tomorrow
    if (fireComponents.hour! > hour || (fireComponents.hour == hour && fireComponents.minute! >= minute) ) {

        dateFire = dateFire.addingTimeInterval(86400)  // Use tomorrow's date
        fireComponents = calendar.components(
            [NSCalendar.Unit.day,
             NSCalendar.Unit.month,
             NSCalendar.Unit.year,
             NSCalendar.Unit.hour,
             NSCalendar.Unit.minute],
            from:dateFire);
    }

    // set up the time
    fireComponents.hour = hour
    fireComponents.minute = minute

    // schedule local notification
    dateFire = calendar.date(from: fireComponents)!


    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = dateFire
    localNotification.alertBody = notificationMessage
    localNotification.repeatInterval = .weekOfYear
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.category = category.rawValue

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

**Cancelling Schedule Local Notifications Sample**

This is no-brainer actually.

```
// Loop through the schedule local notifications and cancel out if there's a weekend

if let scheduledLocalNotifications = UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications {
    for localNotification in scheduledLocalNotifications {
        if let fireDate = localNotification.fireDate {
            if fireDate.isWeekend() {                    UIApplication.shared.cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for taking the time to elaborate! What the situation for me is: I've got a model and I'd like to send the user a notification somewhere during the morning, so they get a reminder. But I don't seem to be able to use background modes for some reason, as it ensures the iOS system itself decides when to notify a user.

But that doesn't give me enough control over the scheduling, can I cancel a notification if a certain condition is met? (The reminder is not necessary anymore)

Comment: @jbehrens94 hi, scheduling a local notification is easy, at any time or any day. Yes you can cancel a scheduled local notification when the user runs the app.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thank you for answering! Do you have an example, maybe? Am I correct in implementing the above named callback?

Comment: Thank you so much! Where would I put this code? In AppDelegate I suppose, but what life cycle hook should I use?

Comment: AppDelegate would be fine. It's up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out Apple doc on background tasks, here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Remote notifications seems especially relevant to what u need, good luck!